# calling out the constructor and assigning values to it from a scanner method

Tags: java

i was trying to make a program that asks the user to create a person or a group of persons and assign names and age to them. So I made a constructor "Try" and a method "AskUser".in AskUser() I use a do/while loop where user is asked to input a name, an age and if he likes to create another person. Now how do I take the input data each time the loop runs, and send it to constructor to create new objects with it? And how these new objects will be called?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try{
    static String name;
    static int age;
    static Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Try(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age= age;
        System.out.println("this is "+name+", and he is "+age+" old.");
    }
    public static void AskUSer(){
        int x=0;
        do {System.out.print("what's the name of the person ?");
            name= a.nextLine();
            System.out.print("how old is he? ");
            age= b.nextInt();
            System.out.print("would u like to creat another person ");
            String yes = c.nextLine();
            if(!(yes.equals("yes"))){x++;}
        } while(x==0);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        AskUSer();
        System.out.print(age+ " "+ name);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need three separate `Scanner` objects for reading from keyboard?  Do you know about `ArrayList`s?

Comment: You are not actually creating new `Try` objects, you are simply setting the static fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the new object in AskUSer and return it as return value. So the code would look like:

```
public static YourObject AskUSer() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aside from how you read from the user ,

it will be appropriate to make a class..
something like :

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

and before entering the loop
you could use an ArrayList to hold people

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

and each time you read the inputs .. instantiate a Person object and add it to the ArrayList

something like :

```
 Person pr=new Person(name,age);
 people.add(pr);
```

Comment: 1.ok, to create a class... what's wrong with my constructor? why do i need a class?

Comment: 2.'   Person pr= new Person(name,age); people.add(pr);   ' wouldn't the loop just overwrite the Person pr over and over again?